# How to set intervals in integers under column, then summing corresponding values fall under the interval?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

```
Key     Type Size Value 
1000001 str    1    -2
1000031 str    1    -1
1000040 str    1    -1
1000052 str    1    -4
1000053 str    1    -2
1000065 str    1    -1
1000066 str    1    -2
1000074 str    1    -1
1000077 str    1    -1
1000101 str    1    -1
```

Hi guys, I've just started python couple of weeks ago and now it looks like i'm facing a dead-end in here.

I have set of tables with which I have to sum the 'Values' corresponding to range of integers (at intervals of 100) under the column 'Key' i.e. sum of 'Value' between 1000001 - 100101 is -16.

The column 'Key' ranges up to ~ 2000000 and I'm facing trouble over iterating the intervals (of 100) using range() statement...

This is my coding so far:

```
f = open("Exercise.gff", 'r')
temp = f.readlines()
f.close()

temp2 = []
for string in temp:
    a = string.split('\t')
    temp2.append(a)

fwd, rev = {}, {}
for i in temp2:
    strand = i[6]
    position = i[3]
    value = i[5]
    if strand == '+':
        fwd[position] = value
    elif strand == '-':
        rev[position] = value
    else:
        print ('error')
        break
```

''' I managed to obtain the table with the coding above, now I want to separate the column 'Key' at interval of 100, and calculate the sum of 'Value' lie within the corresponding range of 'Key' '''

```
summation = {}
for df in fwd:
    column = df[0]
    integers = df[3]
while df[0] in range([1], 2000000, [100]):
    print(df[0])
    df[0] += 100 
    summation[position] = sum(integers)`
```

but this just prints me {} instead of what I wanted.

Could anyone please point out my mistake?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Kang! Your OP looks pretty good! I just have 1 suggestion... Would you please edit the title to turn it into a question, rather than a statement? It might help other people notice your question. Using capitalization & proper punctuation would be nice to see in the title. Other than that, it looks pretty well thought out & explained quite nicely! :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Clomp ! I hope the current title conveys better message.

Comment: You're welcome! I don't know Python, but hopefully someone here at SO will be able to help you figure out what's wrong with the code. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `n // 100 * 100` to round the keys down to the next hundred (or just leave them as strings and remove the last two digits with `s[:-2]`, whichever you prefer), then group them in a dictionary, or `collections.defaultdict`, and calculate the sum.

```
groups = collections.defaultdict(int)
for k, t, s, v in data:
    groups[int(k) // 100 * 100] += int(v)
```

Or, if the data is already sorted by `key`, then you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
groups = {k: sum(int(v[3]) for v in vs) 
          for k, vs in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda d: int(d[0]) // 100 * 100)}
```

Result, in both cases, is `{1000000: -15, 1000100: -1}`, using `data` as

```
text = """1000001 str    1    -2
1000031 str    1    -1
1000040 str    1    -1
1000052 str    1    -4
1000053 str    1    -2
1000065 str    1    -1
1000066 str    1    -2
1000074 str    1    -1
1000077 str    1    -1
1000101 str    1    -1"""
data = [line.split() for line in text.splitlines()]
```

Comment: Hi @tobias_k, your code works like a magic. I'm gonna have to slowly digest it through. Thanks a lot for the amazing code!

Comment: @KangSanKim Glad I could help, take your time. Once you are confident that this works for you, consider accepting the answer to mark the question as being resolved.